# AutoMapper and required fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper

I am trying to create a new record using only some of the fields in my Domain Model. I have created a ViewModel for this and am using AutoMapper.

My code is failing at the minute due to the required fields that I have on my Domain Model. I have added opt=>opt.Ignore() on the necessary field however, I am still having problems.

When I remove [Required] from the StaffPresent field the record is added to the DB.

In my Global.asax.cs

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CustomerSupportRecord, CustomerSupportRecordForCreation>();
Mapper.CreateMap<CustomerSupportRecordForCreation, CustomerSupportRecord>().ForMember(p=>p.StaffPresent, opt=>opt.Ignore());
```

Domain Model

```
public class CustomerSupportRecord
{
    public int CustomerSupportRecordID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string EmployeeID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select an Arrival Time")]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [Display(Name = "Arrival")]
    public DateTime ArrivalTime { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [Display(Name = "Departure")]
    public DateTime? DepartureTime { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a Type")]
    [Display(Name = "Type")]
    public int CustomerSupportTypeID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the staff who were present at the Feedback")]
    [Display(Name = "Staff Present at Feedback")]
    public string StaffPresent { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Setting")]
    public string ReflectionSetting { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Advisor")]
    public string ReflectionAdvisor { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Notes")]
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Comments")]
    public string Comments { get; set; }

    // Navigation Properties
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual CustomerSupportType CustomerSupportType { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class CustomerSupportRecordForCreation
{
    public int CustomerSupportRecordID { get; set; }

    public int CustomerID { get; set; }

    public string EmployeeID { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [Display(Name = "Arrival")]
    public DateTime ArrivalTime { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Type")]
    public int CustomerSupportTypeID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Notes")]
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

And finally my Controller

```
    //
    // GET: /CustomerSupport/CustomerSupportRecord/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.CustomerSupportTypeID = new SelectList(db.CustomerSupportType, "CustomerSupportTypeID", "CustomerSupportTypeName");
        var model = new CustomerSupportRecordForCreation { CustomerID = 1, EmployeeID = "20213" };

        return View("Create", model);

    }

    //
    // POST: /CustomerSupport/CustomerSupportRecord/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CustomerSupportRecordForCreation customersupportrecord)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var newRecord = Mapper.Map<CustomerSupportRecordForCreation, CustomerSupportRecord>(customersupportrecord);
            db.CustomerSupportRecord.Add(newRecord);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
            ViewBag.CustomerSupportTypeID = new SelectList(db.CustomerSupportType, "CustomerSupportTypeID", "CustomerSupportTypeName", customersupportrecord.CustomerSupportTypeID);
            return View(customersupportrecord);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, it's not really clear what you're asking. How is this failing? AutoMap doesn't have anything to do with your validation attributes. You can ignore the StaffPresent field in the mapping, but if your database requires it, you'll need to set it some other way.

Comment: @mfanto Thanks for clearing that up. The database does require the StaffPresent field but just not when the record is first created. It is required under a different ViewModel when the record is updated. Do you know if that means that the validation should be on a ViewModel basis then?

Comment: Yeah, that's probably your best solution. You should always have validation on the ViewModels, to prevent calling your database methods with inconsistent data. It also gives you client side validation (validation before they ever submit the form). But if StaffPresent isn't always required, then you can't [Require] it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AutoMapper's configuration doesn't have anything to do with validation attributes, it just specifies the rules for how to map objects between each-other.

In your case, the mapping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CustomerSupportRecordForCreation, CustomerSupportRecord>().ForMember(p=>p.StaffPresent, opt=>opt.Ignore());
```

tells AutoMapper not to copy the StaffPresent property.

If your database model has a [Required] attribute, you'll still need to set that data elsewhere.

One thing to note based on your comment, it's a good idea to add validation to your ViewModels, as it prevents you from calling your database methods with improper data, gives you [client side validation](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model), and lets you enforce different constraints than your model might require.